# PHP DOM-Document and XPath:fetch class data

Tags: php, html

I've been having an issue trying to parse text in a span cass with DOM. Here is my code example. try to extract some lines out of a webpage - with following technique: with the Extraction of values of attributes of elements with DOMDocument

Here is what i have gathered and learned:

```
$remote = "http://website.com/";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($remote);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$node = $xpath->query('//span[@class="user"]');
echo $node;
```

and this returns the following error -> "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string". I am so lost..

What I am trying to do is parse the user name between this tag;

```
<div class="widget plugin-meta">
            <h3 class="screen-reader-text">Meta</h3>
```

see more below:

Here the concrete example
view-source:https://wordpress.org/plugins/participants-database/
and https://wordpress.org/plugins/participants-database/

```
**goal:** i need the following data:
```

Version:
Last updated:
Active installations:
Tested up:

view-source:https://wordpress.org/plugins/participants-database/

**Proceedings;** i checked the source of the webpage. i tried to find out whether the texte is related to some kind of pattern.i have looked closely and found that all of them have class=”widget plugin-meta”.
Well - This will make extracting them, a piece of cake. I tried with the code below helps to filter html elements based on values of attributes.

but unfortunatly this ends up in a bad result; i need a helping hand and need to know how  to parse the above mentioned data

**goal:** i need the following data:
Version:
Last updated:
Active installations:
Tested up:

Comment: `echo $node;` => `echo $node->item(0)->nodeValue;`

Comment: hello dear spash - many thanks i will try this out!

Comment: `<?php

$remote = "https://wordpress.org/plugins/participants-database/";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($remote);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$node = $xpath->query('//*[@id="post-519"]/div[4]/div[1]/ul/li[2]');
echo $node->item(0)->nodeValue;
?>` see the results:  ` martin@linux-3645:~/dev/php> php p20.php
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/martin/dev/php/p20.php on line 8
martin@linux-3645:~/dev/php> php p20.php`